# Unable to install software using software center: package removal failed error

Tags: software-center, software-installation

While `dpkg -i` works, I can't install software via software centre I get:

```
Package operation failed
the installation or removal of a software package failed
```

I have tried the following:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install -f
```

but still nothing happens. I'm running 14.04 beta

Comment: What is the output of `sudo dpkg --configure -a`?

Comment: The output is : no talloc stackframe at ../source3/param/loadparm.c:4864, leaking memory

Comment: Did you install packages using `dpkg --get-selections`?

Comment: no, I didn't use that command

Comment: I found the solution thank you for your help and your time Sir.

Answer (score 1):

Executing the following commands solved the problem for me:

```
sudo apt-get --fix-broken install
sudo dpkg --configure --pending
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure you are using one of the core window managers.  For example I use openbox for systems that are not responsive enough for gnome and software-center fails in interesting ways.  If I switch my session to gnome by running

```
gnome-session
```

from from the command line suddenly software center starts working.